# futile.logger warn to stderr

Tags: r, logging, stderr

How could I send all logs with level "warn" to stderr instead of stdout but still keep all "info" and "debug" logs in stdout? My setting looks like this:

```
library(futile.logger)
options(warn=1)

logFileName <- paste0(outdir, "/", projectID, ".log")
flog.appender(appender.tee(logFileName))
flog.threshold(DEBUG)
flog.carp(TRUE)
```

Comment: What's the motivation for this? There might be an interesting solution to be had! Do you have another process reading from stderr? What are you doing with the logs?

Comment: @jkix I'd like to draw more attention to the serious log entries (warnings) in the console. The logs are both shown in the console and saved in a file. There is nothing else reading stderr except for the person running the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appender function is responsible for sending the log line to an output
destination; You’ll need to define a custom appender.

In **futile.logger**, the appender only receives the log line, not the log
level associated with it. You could try to infer the log level based on the
line, and choose the destination based on that. The exact logic to do that
will depend on your layout function. With the default option
(`layout.simple()`) that logic could look something like this:

```r
appender.custom <- function(file) {
  function(line) {
    level <- regmatches(line, regexpr("\\w+(?= \\[)", line, perl = TRUE))
    dest <- if (get(level) > WARN) stdout() else stderr()
    cat(line, file = dest, sep = "")
    cat(line, file = file, append = TRUE, sep = "")
  }
}
```

Then you just swap this custom appender for `appender.tee()`:

```r
library(futile.logger)

logFileName <- tempfile(fileext = ".log")
flog.appender(appender.custom(logFileName))
#> NULL
flog.threshold(DEBUG)
#> NULL

local({
  flog.debug("Debug message.")
  flog.info("Info message.")
  flog.warn("Warning message.")
  flog.error("Error message.")
})
#> DEBUG [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Debug message.
#> INFO [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Info message.

cat(readLines(logFileName), sep = "\n")
#> DEBUG [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Debug message.
#> INFO [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Info message.
#> WARN [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Warning message.
#> ERROR [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Error message.
unlink(logFileName)
```

Above, the captured output doesn’t include stderr, but here’s a screenshot
of what the output looks like in the ineractive console:

[image: debug and info as plain text, warn and err as highlighted messages]

Longer term, the way to approach this would probably be a feature request to
the package authors to also pass the log level of the message to the appender
function.

Alternatively, if you’re not commited to sticking with **futile.logger**,
you could use **log4r** which does give the level to the appender. You’ll
still need a custom appender, but there’s no need to try to parse the level:

```r
library(log4r)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'log4r'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     debug

custom_appender <- function(layout = log4r::default_log_layout()) {
  WARN <- log4r::as.loglevel("WARN")
  function(level, ...) {
    msg <- layout(level, ...)
    level <- log4r::as.loglevel(level)
    dest <- if (level >= WARN) stderr() else stdout()
    cat(msg, file = dest, sep = "")
  }
}

log_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".log")
appenders <- list(file_appender(log_file), custom_appender())
logger <- logger("DEBUG", appenders = appenders)

local({
  debug(logger, "Debug message.")
  info(logger, "Info message.")
  warn(logger, "Warning message.")
  error(logger, "Error message.")
})
#> DEBUG [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Debug message.
#> INFO  [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Info message.

cat(readLines(log_file), sep = "\n")
#> DEBUG [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Debug message.
#> INFO  [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Info message.
#> WARN  [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Warning message.
#> ERROR [2020-11-17 16:52:31] Error message.
unlink(log_file)
```