# Using tryCatchLog with futile.logger: write to file instead of console

Tags: r, logging, error-logging

I am using tryCatchLog and want to send all warnings and error messages to a log file. I do not want any output to the console.

In the documentation for [tryCatchLog](https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog) I came across this code snippet:

```
library(futile.logger)
# log to a file (not the console  which is the default target of futile.logger).
# You could also redirect console output into a file if start your R > script with a shell script using Rscript!
flog.appender(appender.file("my_app.log"))
```

The [vignette for tryCatchLog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tryCatchLog/vignettes/tryCatchLog-intro.html) includes the following code snippet to change the logging behavior and send errors to a file instead of the console:

```
  library(futile.logger)

  flog.appender(appender.file("app.log"))

  flog.threshold(ERROR)    # TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

  try(log(-1))             # the warning will not be logged!
```

This suggests to me that I can simply re-direct the messages to a log file using flog.apppender(appender.file()). However, instead of writing to a file I get the following output on the console:

> NULL
> NULL
> Warning in log(-1) : NaNs produced
> [1] NaN

The [vignette for tryCatchLog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tryCatchLog/vignettes/tryCatchLog-intro.html) provides this code example in the Best Practice section:

library(futile.logger)

```
library(tryCatchLog)

options(keep.source = TRUE)        # source code file name and line number tracking
options("tryCatchLog.write.error.dump.file" = TRUE) # dump for post-mortem analysis

flog.appender(appender.file("my_app.log"))  # to log into a file instead of console
flog.threshold(INFO)    # TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

tryCatchLog(source("your_main_script.R"))
```

Adapting the last line of code to `tryCatchLog(log("this will produce an error"))` to make the example easier, I am still not writing to a log file but to the console:

> NULL
> NULL
> Error in log("this will produce an error") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Looking at the [documentation of futile.logger](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futile.logger/futile.logger.pdf) and [examples on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782946/futile-logger-warn-to-stderr) also did not help me. Based on them, I thought the following should write the error message to a file. I am using try() as a stand-in for more involved versions of tryCatchLog() to make sure that it is not an issue with tryCatchLog.

```
library(futile.logger)
flog.appender(appender.file(file.path(getwd(),'logs.txt')))
flog.threshold(WARN)    # TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL
try(log(-1)) # this will create a warning
try(log("this will create an error"))  # this will create an error
```

The command neither creates a log file nor appends an existing one.
Instead, flog.appender() and flog.threshold() return NULL (to the console). And the warning and error message are also printed to the console. Presumably, I am missing something when linking the logger to the file (hence the NULL return value?).

How can I redirect all warnings and errors caught by tryCatchLog to a file (with futile.logger) without ANY output to the console?

Comment: BTW: `futile.logger` has a similar function `ftry()` which you could use instead of standard `try`

Answer (score 0):

The output of `try()` has nothing to do with `futile.logger()`.

If you configure a file appender in `futile.logger` you still have to write your log output using the `flog.*` functions (that's how logging works):

```
library(futile.logger)

flog.info("this is an info log output")
# INFO [2021-12-08 19:51:13] this is an info log output
flog.warn("this is an warning log output")
# WARN [2021-12-08 19:51:14] this is an warning log output
flog.error("this is an error log output")
# ERROR [2021-12-08 19:51:14] this is an error log output
```

I guess what you want is kinda output redirection of the standard or error output (eg. via `capture.output`) but this function does not add logging information like a timestamp and does not support severity level management ("info", "warn", "error"...).

If you want to use `try*()` in combination with logging you can use the CRAN package [`tryCatchLog`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tryCatchLog) which does exactly what you want (and supports `futile.logger` too):

```
library(tryCatchLog)
tryLog(log(-1)) # this will create a warning
tryLog(log("this will create an error"))  # this will create an error
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I actually came across this issue because I want to use tryCatchLog and you suspected correctly that I want to redirect the output. I am editing my post to make this connection clear. I thought there might be a seperate issue with my setting up the file, that's why I did not mentioned tryCatchLog.